# How to force Firefox 56 to reload a legacy add-on?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-overlay

I had been using an old version of Firefox, because I have a legacy add-on which is incompatible with new versions. Now many websites have stopped working in the old version of Firefox, and this forces me to update to Firefox 56 and change the code of the legacy add-on to make it workable.

In general, the legacy add-on works in Firefox 56 but there are some problems that I have to solve.

**My current problem:** I change the add-on files in a text editor, save them, restart Firefox, but instead of using the new add-on files, the browser keeps using the old versions of these files. I have no idea where it keeps them.

I have disabled checking for add-on signing in the browser. The add-on code resides in a folder on a local disk (not compressed). In the Firefox profile, in the folder "extensions" there is a text file that contains the path to that folder. The browser loads add-on, the add-on works, but uses the old versions of the add-on files, even after I change the original files. I tried to disable and then enable the add-on, this did not help at all.

**How can I force Firefox 56 to reload this legacy add-on after I change the add-on files?**

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy to a path the package (xpi) for installed and disabled/incompatible addon.
   (...\Profiles\xxxxxxx.default\extensions)
   Note that files can have names like {b9db16a4-6edc-47ec-a1f4-b86292ed211d}.xpi but using about:support you can find the name associated to this addon.

   2. Uninstall the disabled/incompatible addon
   3. Extract the xpi file (it is a zip file)
   4. Edit install.rdf 
      (contains extension identification and compatibility checks)
      to include a different version
      modify max version 56.*
   5. Edit chrome.manifest
      (contains technical configuration which can be common for all browser and    version or can be  customized per each different web browser or version)
      Modify appversion to apply to your browser version
   6. Add all files to a file.zip
   7. rename the file.zip to file.xpi
   8. Install the addon file on your firefox

You have more details in:
[best-practices-with-firefox-palemoon.html](http://bloglon.blogspot.com/2016/10/best-practices-with-firefox-palemoon.html)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but that is totally not what I was asking.

Comment: As I haven't  read that you removing/installing the addon, I understand that you want to modify files from the installed addon BUT without  modifying the xpi and installing again. Right?  I always modify the xpi and install it again, and it always works fine.

Comment: No, man, there is no xpi at all: "The add-on code resides in a folder on a local disk (not compressed). In the Firefox profile, in the folder "extensions" there is a text file that contains the path to that folder."

Comment: Understood, but I still thinking that you should modify the xpi and install it. If you have not the xpi file in the extensions folder then you can download the xpi using Classic Add-ons Archive ( https://github.com/JustOff/ca-archive/releases  )

Comment: I appreciate your trying to help, but you seem to not understand what I am asking about. I created that add-on, there was no xpi like ever.

Comment: I understood that you are modifying a previously installed addon. Otherwise, do you mean that you create it in the past without generating and installing an xpi package? I understand what you want but this is not the standard procedure, and also I cannot help you. So I just hope someone else can help you